# Sum a column by ID, but skip the first instance?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like the following.

```
A = [{'ID':1, 'Period':1, 'Variable':21}, {'ID':1,'Period':2, 'Variable':12}, 
      {'ID':2, 'Period':2, 'Variable':14}, {'ID':2, 'Period':3, 'Variable':18}]

df = pd.DataFrame(A)
```

I would essentially like to do an operation like `df.groupby('ID').sum()` to get the sum of the `Variable` column, but I need to skip the first period observed for a particular ID. So, for ID=1, I am dropping the observation at period 1, but for ID=2, I am dropping the observation at period 2.

How can I do this?

Comment: so you want something like `df.groupby('ID')['Variable'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:].sum())`?

Comment: That does it. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can slice within each group to ignore the first row and call `sum`:

```
In[46]:
df.groupby('ID')['Variable'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:].sum())

Out[46]: 
ID
1    12
2    18
Name: Variable, dtype: int64
```

If you want all the columns:

```
In[47]:
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:].sum())

Out[47]: 
    ID  Period  Variable
ID                      
1    1       2        12
2    2       3        18
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) to ignore the first occurrence:

```
res = df[df['ID'].duplicated()].groupby('ID').sum()

print(res)

    Period  Variable
ID                  
1        2        12
2        3        18
```

Comment: Was thinking along the same lines, performance-wise it's probably just as taxing as `apply` on a `groupby`+1

Comment: @EdChum, Possibly, yes, I just think the `lambda` adds extra function calls for a large number of groups. While Boolean indexing is applied as a one-off.

Comment: Probably can also create the groupby once and then `group.sum() - group.first()` as well...

Comment: @JonClements Good idea you should post that as an answer. Although saying that `groupby` object is just metadata, you'd still be calling calculating `sum` and then `first` although I'd expect `first` to be fast

Comment: @EdChum meh... it's not really ignoring the first row just countering the effect so I imagine it might be prone to fail under some circumstances... Just throwing it out there in case someone wanted to play with it - but I'm not particularly happy it's a decent answer.

Comment: @JonClements tried it and it works also if there is just a single row for a group, it returns `0` so it does work, it's probably the most readable form IMO

Comment: @JonClements I also think it's probably the neatest solution in this case. The only issue I see is that it only works in the specific case of dropping the first observation rather than, say, the first 2. But, that was not set as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Select necessary observations and then apply aggregation:

```
df[df.ID != df.Period].groupby('ID').sum()
```

**Output**:

```
    Period  Variable
ID                  
1        2        12
2        3        18
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail with `{'ID':2, 'Period':1, 'Variable':14}`? I think it might be exploiting a loophole in the OP's example?

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, my solution based on the rule that first period equals ID. Maybe you're right.